# Search for a String in a Text File using Java 8

Tags: java, file, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have a long text file that I want to read and extract some data out of it. Using JavaFX and FXML, I am using FileChooser to load the file to get the file path. 
My controller.java has the following:

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
        System.out.println(file);
         stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();


    }
```

Sample of text file: Note some of the file content is split between 2 lines. for Example  -Ba\ 10.10.10.3 is part of the first line.

```
net ip-interface create 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.128 MGT-1 -Ba \
10.10.10.3
net ip-interface create 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 G-1 -Ba \
192.168.1.2 
net route table create 10.10.10.5 255.255.255.255 10.10.10.1 -i \
MGT-1
net route table create 10.10.10.6  255.255.255.255 10.10.10.1 -i \
MGT-1
```

I am looking for a way to search this (file) and output the following:

```
MGT-1 ip-interface 10.10.10.2 
MGT-1 Backup ip-interface 10.10.10.3
G-1 ip-interface 192.168.1.1
G-1 Backup Ip-interface 192.168.1.2
MGT-1 route 10.10.10.5 DFG 10.10.10.1
MGT-1 route 10.10.10.6 DFG 10.10.10.1
```

Comment: Can you use awk? http://jawk.sourceforge.net/ And where does DFG come from in your result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am new to Java, so I am looking for pointers.   If I need to use AWK so be it. DFG stands for Default Gateway.  Net route table (creates static route for 10.10.10.5-6 via Default Gateway 10.10.10.1)

Comment: If memory is not a constraint, you can: `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` to get a list containing all the lines. You can then loop over the lines and parse them as you wish.

Comment: any recommendation on how to parse them in a way to get the output above. for example, for pattern "MGT-1 -Ba \" how can I output the next line? 10.10.10.3 How can I do that?  Or how can I out put the IP address after "ip-interface create". 10.10.10.2? I am looking for ideas on how to preform the parse to get the output data mentioned above. I hear Java 8 uses stream, is this something I can use here?

Comment: From where does "Backup" (not in input) and "Ip-interface" (case change) come?

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can read the input file as the stream of lines using `BufferedReader.lines` or `Files.lines`. However the tricky thing here is how to deal with the trailing `"\"`. There are several possible solutions. You may write your own `Reader` which wraps an existing `Reader` and just ignores the slash followed by EOL. Alternatively you can write a custom `Iterator` or `Spliterator` which takes the `BufferedReader.lines` stream as the input and handles this case. I'd suggest to use my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which already has a method for such tasks called [`collapse`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#collapse-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
StreamEx.ofLines(reader).collapse((a, b) -> a.endsWith("\\"), 
                                  (a, b) -> a.substring(0, a.length()-1).concat(b));
```

The first argument is the predicate which is applied for two adjacent lines and should return true if lines should be merged. The second argument is the function which actually merges two lines (we chop the slash via `substring`, then concatenate the next line).

Now you can just split the line by the whitespace and convert it to one or two output lines according to your task. Better to do it by the separate method. The whole code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.util.streamex.StreamEx;

public class ParseFile {
    static Stream<String> convertLine(String[] fields) {
        switch(fields[1]) {
        case "ip-interface":
            return Stream.of(fields[5]+" "+fields[1]+" "+fields[3],
                             fields[5]+" Backup "+fields[1]+" "+fields[7]);
        case "route":
            return Stream.of(fields[8]+" route "+fields[4]+" DFG "+fields[6]);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized input: "+
                                               String.join(" ", fields));
        }
    }

    static Stream<String> convert(Reader reader) {
        return StreamEx.ofLines(reader)
                .collapse((a, b) -> a.endsWith("\\"), 
                          (a, b) -> a.substring(0, a.length()-1).concat(b))
                .map(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::split)
                .flatMap(ParseFile::convertLine);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(Reader r = new InputStreamReader(
            ParseFile.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"))) {
            convert(r).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will do the trick, working on it.... But 2 things 1) how can I pass my file path to your ParseFile.java. and return the output from my controller.java (mentioned above)? 2) how can I combine 2 lines without using your  package (for my learning process)  and print what I need. I can't seem to find this info anywhere.

Comment: I removed your main from ParseFile and I added try(Reader r = new InputStreamReader(
            ParseFile.class.getResourceAsStream("file"))) {
            convert(r).forEach(System.out::println);
        }  inside my controller but it's not working